# Powershell Find file LastWriteTime of file and generate .txt file based on last write date

Tags: powershell

In powershell i would like to return a LastWriteTime value from a file in a directory , then write a file back to that directory with (original file name_LastWriteTime.txt) overwriting the previous days file . LastWriteTime i would like in a YYMMDD format

so an example would be to read the LastWriteTime from  c:\foo\originalfile.mdb and then generate a file called  c:\foo\orignalfile_LastWriteTime.txt (LastWriteTime in a YYMMDD) format

Can you advise on a simple method for doing this

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
Get-Item c:\foo\originalfile.mdb | 
    New-Item -Path {$_.Fullname.Insert($_.FullName.length - 4, $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("_yyMMdd"))} -Type file -Force
```

This approach takes advantage of the fact that you can use a scriptblock for any parameter that accepts pipeline input.  And in the case of `New-Item` the `Path` parameter accepts pipeline input.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Specify the file name you are looking for.

$file = "originalfile.mdb"



# Create a date variable by getting the
# last write time and formatting it with Get-Date

$date = Get-Date (ls | ? {$_.Name -match $file}).LastWriteTime -Format yyMMdd



# Create a new file using the original name minus the file ext
# and add the date onto the end.

New-Item "$($file -replace '\..*$','')_$($date)" -Type File
```